# How to command Babylon in PotPlayer to get a term and translate it from the subtitle by mouse?

Tags: windows-7, babylon, daum-pot-player

I want to translate a word by commanding [Babylon](http://www.babylon-software.com) to get the word in [PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net)’s subtitle (by mouse) by PotPlayer’s “online word searching” feature.

Now what’s the equvalet string to the `%s` *in Windows language* for commanding Babylon to translate the word, or is it possible at all?

Comment: There isn't one. `%s` is language independent. It's a command line parameter or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I use artha for that, just remove all the search engines from Pot Player's word searching feature leaving copy to clip board. Now when, you will pause the video and click on text, and then press artha global hotkey, it will popup the meaning of selected word. Just keep in mind to select never in "Stay on Top" option.